# cakephp user/login redirects to users/login automatically

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I have a model called "user" and a controller for "user" with an action "login".

The controller is empty right now as I'm simply testing the page, however, going to www.mysite.com/user/login redirects me automatically to www.mysite.com/user**s**/login and then says that the users controller does not exist.

I know it doesn't exist but I'm not TRYING to access the page, why is it redirecting me there?

I also have a /user/register page which works fine.

```
function login()
{

}
```

Is this due to some form of cakephp's built in functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always have

```
www.mysite.com/users/login
```

Because your models are always pluralized. Remember, you should have:

```
model/user.php
controller/users_controller.php
views/users/...
```

Answer (score 0):

it's for this code in the app_controller.php:

```
 class AppController extends Controller
    {
      var $components = array('Auth');
    }
```

you "should" have login() function.